# Trouble with agent state chart

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to create an agent statechart where a transition should happen every day at 4 pm (except weekends).

I have already tried:
1. a conditional transition (condition: getHourOfDay() == 16)
2: A timeout transition that will "reinsert" my agent into the chart every 1 s and check if time = 16.

My code is still not running, does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

[image]

This is my statechart view. Customer is a single resource that is supposed to "get" the products out of my stock everyday at 4pm. It is supposed to happen in the "Active" state.

[image]

I have set a timeout transition (from Active-Active) that runs every 1s.

[image]

Inside my "Active" state in the "entrance action" i wrote my code to check if it is 4 pm and run my action if so.

I thought since i set a timeout transition it would check my condition every 1s, but apparently it is not working.

Comment: would be helpful if you show your statechart... and since you ask a lot of questions in stackoverflow, you should start marking those that got answered... you have never done that.

Comment: a few options why your transitions don't work: the current state doesn't have the transition you want, your condition is never evaluated, your simulation never gets to 4pm... that's what I can think of

Comment: Thank you for your comments Felipe, I just added the statechart pictures to the question. Also, thank you for warning me about the question marking, i did not know i could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your agent does not enter the Active state via an internal transition.

Redraw the transition to actually go out of the Active state and then enter it again as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use condition-based transitions, for performance reasons. In your case, it also never triggers because it is only evaluated when something happens in the model. Incidentally, that is not the case at 4pm.

re your timeout approach: Why would you "reinsert" your agent into its own statechart? Not sure I understand...

Why not set up a schedule or event with your recurrence requirement and make it send a message to the statechart: `stateChart.fireEvent("trigger!");`. In your statechart, add a message-based transition that waits for this message. This will work.

Be careful to understand the difference between the `Statechart.fireEvent()` and the `Statechart.receiveMessage()` functions, though.

PS: and agree with Felipe: please start using SOF the way it is meant, i.e. also mark replies as solved. It helps us but also future users to quickly find solutions :-) cheers

Comment: Thank you Benjamin for your answer and tips! I just uploaded pictures from my simulation. The thing is that, I need my Agent to collect the itens that will be dellivered to my client every day at 4pm. I would like for that to happen in the "Active" state of my agent. I created a statechart because I'm working with rescheduling and my agent "client" needs to talk with my agent "schedule" in case something needs to be agreed in means of delivery quantities.